# jQuery Custom pop up issue

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to create a custom css and jQuery popup but its not working properly.Please see my code below and let me know where I am wrong? I want if someone click on "Click Me" button a popup will open and if user click outside the popup then popup will hide.

I have already included jQuery in my code.
Here is my code:

```
<style>
    .maskarea {
    width: 100%;
    height:700px;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .7);
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    display:none;
}
.popup {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    position: fixed;
    left: 50%;
    background: #ccc;
    margin-left: -150px;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -150px;
}
</style>
<script>
$(function(){
     $(".hit").click(function(){
        $(".maskarea").show();
     })
})
</script>
</head>
<body>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="hit">Click Me</a>
    <div class="maskarea">
        <div class="popup">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: From looking at [this codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pgvNva) the popup works fine when opening. You simply need to create a click handler on the maskarea to hide the popup when clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use various jquery plugins for popup like fancybox, lightbox etc. but if you want to use your custom code you can code your popup like :

```
    <style>
    .maskarea {
        width: 100%;
        height:700px;
        background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .7);
        position: fixed;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        display:none;
    }
    .popup {
        width: 300px;
        height: 300px;
        position: fixed;
        left: 50%;
        background: #ccc;
        top: 50%;
    }
    </style>
    <script>
    $(function(){
        $(".hit").click(function(){
            var windowHeight = $(window).height();  //Get current height of window or screen 
            var popup = $(".popup");    //cache the popup
            var marginTop = '-'+parseInt(popup.height()/2)+'px';  //Dynamically  get height of a popup div, and make it half for negative margin
            var marginLeft = '-'+parseInt(popup.width()/2)+'px';  //Dynamically  get width of a popup div, and make it half for negative margin
            popup.css({'margin-left':marginLeft,'margin-top':marginTop});
            $(".maskarea").height(windowHeight).show(); //assign windows height to maskarea
        })

        $(document).mouseup(function(e){
            var box = $('.popup');
            if(!box.is(e.target)&&box.has(e.target).length===0){
                $('.maskarea').hide();
            }
        })
    })
    </script>

<body>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="hit">Click Me</a>
    <div class="maskarea">
        <div class="popup">

        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks Sanchit,  your code clearly explain most of the things. Thanks :)

Comment: Also look for e.stopPropagation().

Answer (score 4):

**1st :** you need to create click event if user click on .maskarea  hide it

**2nd :** another click event for .popup div to prevent .maskarea click

try this

```
$(function(){
     $(".hit").click(function(){
        $(".maskarea").show();
     });
     // if user click on .maskarea  hide it
     $('.maskarea').on('click', function(){
       $(this).hide();
     });
     // use e.stopPropagation(); for .popup div to prevent .maskarea click
     $('.popup').on('click', function(e){
       e.stopPropagation();
     });
})
```

[**working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/3jfj64gp/)

read about [e.stopPropagation()](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/)

Comment: Thank you Mohamed-Yousef  :)

Comment: @RajeshGautam you're welcome .. and please keep your attention in e.stopPropagation(); .. it will help you click inside popup div without hiding the maskarea   div ..  Good Luck :)

Answer (score 2):

You were almost there, all you were missing out on was the close handler. Here's an example [pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pgvNva).

Using the following HTML

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="hit">Click Me</a>
<div class="maskarea">
  <div class="popup">
  </div>
</div>
```

With this CSS

```
.maskarea {
  width: 100%;
  height: 700px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .7);
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  display: none;
}

.popup {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  position: fixed;
  left: 50%;
  background: #ccc;
  margin-left: -150px;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -150px;
}
```

And this JS

```
$(function() {
  $(".hit").click(function() {
    $(".maskarea").show();
  });
  $(".maskarea").click(function() {
    $(this).hide();
  });
  $('.popup').on('click', function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
  });
});
```

You should be able to have a functioning popup.